# Make a simple git alias

Tags: git, macos, alias

Environment: Mac OSX 10.10

It's a simple question, but I am not familiar with it.
Here is what I want, I want to make a commend like `gpgh`, and it will do `git push` and then `git push heroku master`.

I wrote a `bash` and put those two command into it, and I could use `bash ./gpgh.bash` to execute. But how do I make a easy way, just type `gpgh` to do this feature ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this into your bash profile.

```
alias gpgh='git push; git push heroku master'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this: `alias gpgh="git push && git push heroku master"`. 
If you add that to your .bash_profile it'll persist.

Comment: Thank, you've been a great help.